# Replacing month in TimeStamp from Date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am new to Oracle DB and have a situation in hand.
I have two tables.

```
Table1 [ ID, MY_DATE ]
Table2 [ ID, MY_TIMESTAMP]
```

I need to pick the `month` alone from `Table1.MY_DATE` and replace the corresponding month at `Table2.MY_TIMESTAMP`.
Both Table1 and Table2 are joined by ID.

How do I pick the month alone from a Date column and replace month alone in a TimeStamp field.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: which formats these both dates are in....

Comment: Dates are in the format 01-Jan-2012

Comment: @Abhinav- Dates in Oracle don't have formats! dates are a number representing the date, when you want to show them then you format them (or let oracle do it implicitly according to NLS params)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE SO_BUFFER_TABLE_13 BT2
   SET BT2.MY_TIMESTAMP = TO_DATE((TO_CHAR(BT2.MY_TIMESTAMP, 'DD') || '/' ||
                                  (SELECT TO_CHAR(BT1.MY_DATE, 'MM')
                                      FROM SO_BUFFER_TABLE_12 BT1
                                     WHERE BT1.ID = BT2.ID) || '/' ||
                                  TO_CHAR(BT2.MY_TIMESTAMP,
                                           'YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')),
                                  'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')

Hope is helps